# QField - Get attribute from selected feature

Tags: attribute-table, layouts, qfield

My objective is to get a automatic layout with QFIELD based on a selected object (in QField) and with some attributes of the selected object.

The project works fine on QGIS but it seems that the layout of QField doesn't recognize the selected object.

Exemple of code using to get an attribute from the selected object on the layout :

```
concatenate(CASE WHEN is_selected () is true THEN "name_of_column" ELSE '' END)
```

An idea?

Answer (score 6):

In Qfield 1.9.1 just select the feature, open attribute form and press 3 points button. There is "Print Atlas Feature to PDF" function.

[image: 1]